# Error in filter statement - Shiny Application

Tags: r, shiny

I've added a date filter to my Shiny App. Now I want to filter the data frame dynamically according to the date input.

I tried this as follows in **`ui.R`**:

```
fluidPage(
      selectInput(
        "analysis_period",
        "analysie period:",
        c(
          "Last Year" = "LY",
          "Past 90 days" = "ND",
          "Past 30 days" = "TD",
          "Last Week" = "LW"
        )
      )
     )
```

In my server section I have:

```
date_input <- reactive({
if (input$analysis_period== "NT") {
  as.Date(Sys.time()) - 90
}

else if (input$analysis_periodm == "DT") {
  as.Date(Sys.time()) - 30
}

else if (input$analysis_periodum == "LW") {
  as.Date(Sys.time()) - 7
}

else if (input$analysis_period == "LY") {
  m = as.POSIXlt(as.Date(Sys.time()))
  m$year = m$year - 1
  m
}
})
```

Then I want to load the data frame and filter it using the filter:

```
data2 = data[, c('A', 'B', 'C')]
data2 <- filter(data2, date_input())
```

But when I start the app I always get the error:

> ```
> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
> Evaluation error: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. 
> (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive 
> expression or observer.).
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `else if` should start at the same row after closing bracket, i.e.: `if(){}else if(){}else if....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it. When I executed the reactive inside a reactive expression or observer it works. Thank you guys for your help.

I did it like this:

```
  output$x1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
df <- data2
df<- filter(df, df$date >= dateinput())
df
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `date_input` in a reactive function, but if necessary you can get value outside by using `isolate()`.

But the goal of reactive function in Shiny it's to use `isolate()` at the minimum.

I don't know if your  `data2 = data[, c('A', 'B', 'C')]` is outside a reactive function.

links:

- https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/isolation.html
- https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/isolate.html

Comment: Thanks phili_b. Yes, it's outside of the reactive function. I'm not quite sure yet what I need to adapt here. Did I understand correctly that I first have to isolate the query and that it is only used during a user interaction.

Comment: yes, it's that :) " I first have to isolate the query and that it is only used during a user interaction"

Comment: Okay, and how can I use this? With a reactive function around the data query? I've never used isolation before. Sorry for asking :)

Comment: I 've made a mistake _you have to NOT isolate the query and that it is only used during a user interaction_ , except particular needs `isolate()` is only for particular purpose.